# Как сделать поочерёдное выполнение запросов в Flask?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask

Суть приложения - отдаёт пользователю сгенерированную картинку по запросу. Генерация картинки занимает несколько секунд и использует видеокарту. При одновременных запросах видеокарта нагружается генерацией сразу нескольких картинок и функция выдаёт ошибку.

Требуется сделать так, чтобы одновременно генерировалось не большой одной картинки.

В простом телеграм боте на Telebot решил это путём организации очереди запросов. Все запросы помещались в очередь, после чего выполнялись последовательно и по готовности отправлялись пользователям. В Flask затрудняюсь реализовать подобное, так как из-за хитрых контекстов запроса просто помещать переменные request в глобально объявленную очередь не выходит.

```
@app.route("/url")
def fun():
    request_info = request.args.get("info")
    # ВОТ ТУТ ПОДОЖДАТЬ КОГДА ВСЕ ДРУГИЕ ЗАПРОСЫ ВЫПОЛНЯТСЯ
    image = long_time_fun_image_generator(request_info)
    return make_response(data = image)
```